# How to compare directories with binary files

Tags: files, file-comparison

I'd like to compare directories with binary files. Actually, I'm not interested in what the actual differences between files are, but to know if there's a differ (and what files differ). Previously I used `meld`, but it's cannot compare binary files.

What such file comparison tool can do this?

**NOTE:** It doesn't matter if it's a graphical tool or is just has a command-line.

Comment: Does the tool need to be graphical like `meld` or will things like `diff` and `comm` do?

Comment: @terdon - It doesn't matter. Thank you. I expanded the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can easily be done with `diff`. For example:

```
$ ls -l foo/
total 2132
-rwxr-xr-x 1 terdon terdon 1029624 Nov 18 13:13 bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 terdon terdon 1029624 Nov 18 13:13 bash2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 terdon terdon  118280 Nov 18 13:13 ls

$ ls -l bar/
total 1124
-rwxr-xr-x 1 terdon terdon 1029624 Nov 18 13:14 bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 terdon terdon  118280 Nov 18 13:14 ls

$ diff bar/ foo/
Only in foo/: bash2
```

In the example above, the `foo/` and `bar/` directories contain binary files and `bash2` is only in `foo/`.

So, you could run something simple like:

```
$ diff bar/ foo/ && echo "The directories' contents are identical"
```

That will show you the different files, if any, or print "The directories' contents are identical" if they are. To compare subdirectories and any files they may contain as well, use `diff -r`. Combine it with `-q` to suppress the output for text files.

Comment: You can recursively compare with `diff` too using the `-r` switch.

Comment: and `-q` to disable actual diff output for text files.

Comment: Presumably this will perform a binary comparison of `foo/bash` and `bar/bash`?

Comment: If you use the `-r` flag (see last paragraph) yes. If not, it will just compare file names.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare two files using `cmp` command

**usage:**

`cmp file1 file2`

It will give the number bytes difference and line number

Comment: cmp can't do recursive comparison.  The OP wants to compare directories, not files.

Answer (score 1):

A complete comparison, showing identical, different and only in one or the other folder or subfolders:

```
diff -rqs bar/ foo/
```

(You'll get some output for each file, no need for the 'directories identical')